# How can I solve graphical system lock issue while connecting to VNC Server?

Tags: rhel, vnc

While connecting to a VNC server the graphical system is locked up while I try to connect via VNC-viewer. I can initiate a connection but the auth screen shows 'Authentication Error' and does not allow to type the password. [image]
Following is the log message I am getting:
[image]

My service file is as follows:

```
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/runuser -l **USER** -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l **USER** -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24"
PIDFile=/home/**USER**/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here USER is an actual user.

xstartup file looks like:

```
#  cat ~/.vnc/xstartup

#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
 [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
 vncconfig -iconic &
 dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

I am using RHEL 8.2. Can anybody help me how to resolve this issue. I am a new Linux user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using runuser in a systemd service?  Was this ported from an old init script without knowing of the User= config option

Comment: Thanks for the response @jsbillings. Can you please clarify your point in details. I am a new Linux user so kind of having hard time understanding things!

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=